# Wait messages from RabbitMQ at Hub class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rabbitmq, signalr

I use ASP.NET MVC + SignalR to send messages from server to client.

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    static List<User> Users = new List<User>();

    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void Connect(string userName)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;
        if (!Users.Any(x => x.ConnectionId == id))
        {
            Users.Add(new User { ConnectionId = id, Name = userName }); 
        }
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var item = Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
        if (item != null)
        {
            Users.Remove(item);
        }

        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

How can I wait messages from RabbitMQ to send these messages to client at ASP.NET MVC?

For example, I can write call "ReadLine()" method in Console Application and wait messages from RabbitMQ:

```
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{

};
channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                     noAck: true,
                     consumer: consumer);
Console.ReadLine();
```